# How to know if a node is surrounded?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm an IT student working on a school project. We are building a game where 2 players can fight over and colonize planets. A specific game mechanic is that if a player creates a perimeter of planets, surrounding some other planets, he also gets all the planets on the inside of the perimeter.

The idea is explained here in detail: http://www.lostgarden.com/2005/06/space-crack-using-planets-to-build.html

So now I need to write an algorithm to detect whether a perimeter has been build / planets are surrounded. The planets and connections are saved in the database like a graph of nodes. Every node knows his neighbors. How do I know if a planet (node) is surrounded? Or how do I know if a perimeter exists and surrounds one or more planets?

I'm don't know much about graph-theory but was hoping this problem isn't too hard for someone who knows anything about it. Thanks!

Comment: You could just save a data structure for each one of the perimeters  that has a list of the planets it has as nodes, and then apply raycasting(or other algorithm) to know if the [point is in the polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this depends quite a bit on how you've stored the structure. It looks like what you have is a planar graph that is a triangulation (all faces have 3 edges) other than the designated "outside" face (defined by the vertices near the edges of the play area).

If this is the case, then keep track of the vertices on the boundary. Now if a "perimeter" is formed, delete the cycle forming the perimeter from the graph. What you will be left with is a disconnected graph. Now find the connected components of that graph, an algorithm is outlined here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Now a planet is "captured" by the "perimeter" if and only if it is in a connected component of the new graph that does not contain a vertex of the boundary.

Comment: How would I detect that a perimeter is formed?

Comment: After each turn, you can find all the cycles in the graph. This paper gives a good algorithm for this:

http://dutta.csc.ncsu.edu/csc791_spring07/wrap/circuits_johnson.pdf

The paper is in terms of directed graphs, while your graph is undirected, but you can think of your undirected graph as a directed graph by replacing all edges by two directed edges in both directions.